# RTL support in Ace Editor - Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Arrow keys moves the cursor in opposite direction when I type Hebrew.
Is there any solution?
Thanks

Comment: This is the default convention of windows editors, If you want the mac editor behavior too, try opening github feature request about this.

Answer (score -2):

There is [an open GitHub issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1429) concerning this problem. Unfortunately, it seems that a *real* right-to-left support is not implemented yet.

Anyways, you could try one of the following approaches for a workaround solution:

1) Use the [CSS `direction` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction) in your Ace container to force the right-to-left rendering. Although it's rather about text styling, maybe it could help.

2) If that doesn't help, you can try to catch arrow events and send "fake events" instead (see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12187302/2764486) for code reference):

```
function triggerFakeKeyEvent(keycode) {
    let keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    let initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ? "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";

    keyboardEvent[initMethod](
        "keydown", // event type: keydown, keyup, keypress
        true,      // bubbles
        true,      // cancelable
        window,    // view: should be window
        false,     // ctrlKey
        false,     // altKey
        false,     // shiftKey
        false,     // metaKey
        keycode,   // keyCode: unsigned long - the virtual key code, else 0
        0          // charCode: unsigned long - the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
    document.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    // left arrow key
    if(event.keyCode === 37) {
        event.preventDefault();  // ignore the original keyboard event
        triggerFakeKeyEvent(39);
    }
    // right arrow key
    else if(event.keyCode === 39) {
        event.preventDefault();  // ignore the original keyboard event
        triggerFakeKeyEvent(37);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try what you suggested!

Comment: The event isn't performs when the focus is on the editor. In the rest of the document is working. I'm thinking to attach your code to: editor.textInput.getElement()